# Extract string from tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract from below table. I cut it after the second `<td>`, with six more to follow. All eight strings need to be extracted, e.g. in the example below I would want the values `61.5`, `56.43`, etc.

The code below only gives me the first value, `61.5`. How can I get the remaining values?

```
 soup.find("div", {"class":"value"}).text


<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Dornum</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">61.5</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>
<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Emden EMS</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">56.43</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension: `[ float(el.text) for el in soup.find_all('div', 'value') ]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `soup.find_all()` to obtain a list of matching elements, then grab the `text` attribute for each element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Dornum</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">61.5</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>
<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Emden EMS</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">56.43</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = [element.text for element in soup.find_all("div", "value")]

>>> data
[u'61.5', u'56.43']
```

Or, if you want them as floats:

```
data = [float(element.text) for element in soup.find_all("div", "value")]
>>> data
[61.5, 56.43]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <td class="flow">
 <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Dornum</div>
 <div class="data"><div class="value">61.5</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
 </td>
 <td class="flow">
 <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Emden EMS</div>
 <div class="data"><div class="value">56.43</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
 </td>
```

try this out :

```
 temp = soup.select('div[class="value"]') 
 result = []
 for i in temp:
     result.append(i.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to  get all the values using find_all() in BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Dornum</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">61.5</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>
<td class="flow">
    <div class="heading" style="min-height: 63px;">Emden EMS</div>
    <div class="data"><div class="value">56.43</div> MSm<sup>3</sup>/d</div>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
out=[]
for elem in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"value"}):
    out.append(elem.text)
```