# Regular expression for finding integers in the HTML lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract integer values from HTML line of code that I have extracted using BeautifulSoup package, however I'm getting the following error message and I'm not sure why.

Each span tag retrieves with no issues and it looks like this:

```html
TAG  <span class="comments">2</span>
```

Are there any changes I need to implement in the regex or is it some actual problem with my code?

I tried to modify the regex, and remove the numlist = list()

```py
[...]
import re

numlist = list()
totalsum = 0
count = 0

[...]

#Retrieve all of the span tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
count = count + 1
    numlist = re.findall('([0-9]+)', tag)
    if len(numlist) > 0:
        for item in numlist:
            totalsum = totalsum + int(item)

print("Count ",count)
print("Total Sum", totalsum)
```

totalsum function supposed to sum up all values found, but I get the following error message in the Command Prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment1week4.py", line 23, in <module>
    numlist = re.findall('([0-9]+)', tag)
  File "C:\Users\konst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: For your own sake, don't. Use an HTML parser

Comment: You said you already used beautifulsoup, so why not extract the numbers with it?

Comment: DeepSpace, I'm doing this as part of the assignment for one course. Only using BeautifulSoup as an html parser here:

```
url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context = ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```
However I'm not sure how to extract an actual integer to calculate the sum out of that extracted line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a code problem. You're getting a `TypeError` that is telling you that you need to pass a string into `re.findall`. We know that `'([0-9]+)'` is a string, so it must be `tag` that isn't. IIRC, finding all tags of a type with BeautifulSoup returns an array of objects representing the HTML tags, not a list of strings.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212766/extract-string-from-tag-with-beautifulsoup) has some information about getting the text of strings, but if you don't want to look over all of it, it boils down to using the `.text` attribute, e.g. `numlist = re.findall('([0-9]+)', tag.text)`.