# How can I extract the result string in BeautifulSoap?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

start_url = 'https://www.example.com'
downloaded_html = requests.get(start_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(downloaded_html.text, "lxml")
full_header = soup.select('div.reference-image')
full_header
```

The Output of the above code is;

```
[<div class="reference-image"><img src="Content/image/all/reference/c101.jpg"/></div>,
 <div class="reference-image"><img src="Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg"/></div>,
 <div class="reference-image"><img src="Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg"/></div>]
```

I would like to extract the `img src` content as below;

```
["Content/image/all/reference/c101.jpg",
 "Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg",
 "Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg"]
```

How can I extract it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212766/extract-string-from-tag-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: This is a blatant duplicate of [Extracting an attribute value with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup).

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaVarghese, it perfectly does. Also, is there a way to handle this situation with BeautifulSoup's own functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that, just iterate through the result:

```
img_srcs = []
for i in full_header:
    img_srcs.append(i.find('img')['src'])
```

This gives:

```
['Content/image/all/reference/c101.jpg', 'Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg', 'Content/image/all/reference/c102.jpg']
```

Here is a one-liner for this:

```
img_srcs = [i.find('img')['src'] for i in full_header]
```